# MySQL Table Compare Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have looked and can't seem to find anything that is working.  Please if there is already something then I do apologize ahead of time.  I am trying to get the total amount of number not in a list of 25Million.  Below is the query I have tried and only to get a loop type result.  Everything else I have tried fails.

```
SELECT ca_exact_data_only.*
  FROM ca_ho.ca_exact_data_only ca_exact_data_only
       INNER JOIN ca_ho.ca_dnc ca_dnc
          ON (ca_exact_data_only.Phone <> ca_dnc.Phone)
```

Any help would be most greatful.

Answer (score 0):

give it try

```
SELECT            a.*
FROM              tbl_1 a 
NATURAL LEFT JOIN tbl_2 b
on tbl_1.id = tbl_2.id
WHERE             b.phone IS NULL
```

OK, Since you are joining by a natural join, it merges two tables and sets the not identical cells as Null. and then a where condition for Null phone number in table b

Comment: Can you please elaborate a smidge...I think I get what you're trying to say...haven't had my coffee yet this morning.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the table ca_dnc contains the 25million numbers. If I'm wrong simply swap the tables in the statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM ca_ho.ca_dnc ca_dnc
  LEFT
  JOIN ca_ho.ca_exact_data_only ca_exact_data_only
    ON ca_dnc.Phone = ca_exact_data_only.Phone
 WHERE ca_exact_data_only.Phone IS NULL;
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this within Toad.  Reason being is when I try and run this within Console it seems to crash the server.  When running in toad...I don't get any results right away.  It merely sits there and appears to be trying to think about it.  I'm using MySQL version 5.6.17 if that helps figure this out easier.

Comment: @Eric Do you have any indexes on the tables that we should know of?

Comment: No indexes...all I have in ca_dnc is just the column for the number.